# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: angular, google-api, localhost, google-places-api

I'm trying to make a call to google places api so i can get some details about a location but i guess i'm not allowed on localhost..

What should i do to get access to the api?

I tried to add localhost at http referrers on my api key but it didn't fix.

[This is how i make the get call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVqYS.png)

[Here i call that function, after i get the place_id from google places autocomplete input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54xp.png)

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRNA0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some code snippet or you can create plunker or stackblitz link or may be you can share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by allowing CORS with an extension (Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Another option would be through a proxy but the extension fixed it quicker.